# SSRS Report Viewer Parameters

Tags: sharepoint, parameters, ssrs-2008

I am developing SSRS reports for my Sharepoint site. My environment is Sharepoint Server 2007, SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 (Sharepoint Integrated Mode). I am using SQL Server Reporting Services Report Viewer Web Part (Add - In for sharepoint) to view my reports. Though it renders my report but I am not able to pass parameter to my report.

I have created another webpart to pass parameter to Report Viewer. My web part implements ITransformable interface. But When I go to Connections -> Get Report Parameteres From - > (My Web Part). A Web Pop Up opens showing Filters -> (My Filter Name from my Web Part), Filtered Parameters -> A DropDown (disabled) With "No Parameters" as DropDown item, though my Report Viewer identifies report's parameter.

Please help me.

Thanks a lot.

Kind Regards
Vivek

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that ITransformableFilterValues.AllowMultipleValues returns **false** (implemented by the provider web part). It seems that SSRS report parameters do not accept multiple values.